# A particle with null properties

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, elementary-particles

Let's imagine a particle with spin 0, zero mass, zero electrical charge, and so on - each of it's inherent quantum properties or charges is zero (like those in the list on the side [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavour_(particle_physics))). The particle's energy and momentum may take any physical value. Is there anything that forbids the existence of such a particle?

It would have at least some interactions with the fundamental forces - for example with gravity like photons do, so a theory of quantum gravity could potentially have a term for a particle like this in it's Lagrangian, and maybe through this it could interact with other particles.

If such a particle can exist, is there any theory that predicts it?

Comment: Does it have zero energy and momentum? What's the list of "quantum properties and charges"? Also, the Lagrangian itself determines which interactions the particle participates in.

Comment: @probably_someone yes, the particle may have energy and momentum.

Comment: Listing the charges of a particle does *not* uniquely define the dynamics of a particle. You need to write down the Lagrangian its corresponding field is involved in to fix the dynamics.

Comment: In that case, what you're talking about is a _real scalar field_. It's one of the first objects that we study in QFT, and is used to describe the residual nuclear force through the Yukawa interaction (with $\pi^0$ as the scalar particles).

Comment: @ACuriousMind the question is whether given the properties I imposed, is it possible to write a valid Lagrangian?

Comment: @proton Yep, given that list, a real scalar field would satisfy your requirements.

Comment: Sure, e.g. $(\partial \phi)^2$. Whether self-interactions of $\phi$ or some other terms are allowed depends on what, exactly, you consider an "inherent quantum property" or a "charge" - those are not terms with full formal definitions, so the question is underspecified.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I meant all the properties that listing them uniquely defines a particle. Is there no formal term for it?

Comment: No, because what "uniquely defines a particle" is its corresponding field together with the Lagrangian said field appears in, not some list of numbers.

Comment: @proton Even if you're looking specifically at the Standard Model Lagrangian, the issue is that some "particles" only exist in a certain gauge. For example, the massless spin-zero chargeless Goldstone bosons produced by the Higgs mechanism would satisfy your requirements, but are "eaten by the gauge," in a sense. The concept of "ghosts" in general QFT also relates to this.

Comment: @proton So it's not that there's no formal definition; rather, it's that there _is no such object in general,_ especially if you look at particles in contexts other than the Standard Model (e.g. field-theoretic descriptions of condensed matter, effective field theories for nuclear forces, etc.)